# NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar::Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

I have a class that I made in the **lib** directory of a rails project

```
module Foo
  class Bar

    def initialize(partner)
      dir = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'partner', "#{partner}.yml")
    end
  end
end
```

When I initialize this class **dir**  throws an error; I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar::Rails`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you run this code (e.g. through a request, or from a task, or standalone)? Another hacky method would be `'..', 'config', ...`

Comment: can you post your application.rb

Comment: do you have it sorted out? :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I guess, I added require rails to the top of the file and that works. Feels like a code smell but it works.